# How to wait for data from a parent in a component method

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an API call from a layout and I want to send an object with API data to my component.

Problem is, my object is empty as the method is called in the `mounted()` function. So, I need to execute this function only if I have data on my API service.

```
axios.get('/class')
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data.results)
        response.data.results.forEach(element => {
            const object = {
                clientId: element.client.objectId,
                price: element.price || 0,
                driverId: element.objectId || null
            }
            this.serviceData.tripsInfo.push(object) // service data is the object will send to the the component
            ...
```

HTML :

```
<class title="List of class" :points="serviceData"/>
```

`class` component:

```
props: {
    points: {} // here is the layout data
},
mounted () {
    console.log(this.points)
    const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue
    this.totalPrices = this.points.class.map(x => x.price).reduce(reducer) // here I got a problem (Reduce of empty array with no initial value")
},
```

Comment: You could use a watch function to run the reducer when the data is returned

Comment: and how to do that ? it's my first time with Js

Comment: your populating `tripsInfo`, not `class`

Answer (score 1):

A [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) function will watch for whichever prop or data property has the same name and run the corresponding function each time its dependency updates.

```
props: {
    points: Object
},
watch: {
    points() {
        const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue
        this.totalPrices = this.points.class.map(x => x.price).reduce(reducer)
    }
}
```

So, essentially, as soon as `points` is populated with data, the reducer will run.

Alternatively, you can condense all of this down to a computed property:

```
computed: {
    totalPrices: function() {
        const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue
        return this.points.class.map(x => x.price).reduce(reducer)
    }
}
```

Comment: I got an error (Type of the default value for 'points' prop must be a function)

Comment: Ok now nothing happened I've used console.log('test') inside my watch function to test it execution but I found the the fuction is not launched

Comment: Sounds like an issue with your Axios request. Have you checked the data is being returned and is set to `serviceData` properly?

Comment: Nope my Axios request it works fine and now I have fixed that problem using V-if before the excution of my component <class title=""  v-if="serviceData.class.length > 0" :points="serviceData"/>

Comment: The watcher should work in that case. Either way, if you can use a `v-if`, that's definitely the better option.

Answer (score 0):

Can use : `V-if` to solve this like:

```
<class title="" v-if="serviceData.class.length > 0" :points="serviceData"/>
```